# Spotify web API now playing from bash

Tags: bash, spotify

I'm attempting to use the Spotify web API to get the currently playing track information to display on a conky widget without the need for the native Spotify player. So far I have managed to reliably get the authorization key, but that's about as far as I've been able to figure out, many dozens of examples, tutorials, and attempts later I'm still stuck.

How would I go about getting the access token, and refreshing it for that matter?

This is the script that works so far

```
client_id=$(jq -r '.id' ./spotify_creds.json)
client_secret=$(jq -r '.secret' ./spotify_creds.json)
port=8082
if [ -f "./auth_key" ]; then
    echo "auth key found"
else 
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A$port%2F
auth_endpoint=https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?response_type=code\&client_id=$client_id\&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri
scopes="user-read-currently-playing"
encoded_scopes=$(echo $scopes| tr ' ' '%' | sed s/%/%20/g)
xdg-open $auth_endpoint\&scope=$encoded_scopes

(echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin:*\nContent-Length:65\n\n<html><script>open(location, '_self').close();</script></html>\n" | nc -l $port -q 0 > "auth_key")
fi

code=$(echo $(cat ./auth_key) | grep GET | cut -d' ' -f 2 | cut -d'=' -f 2)
echo " authentication code"
echo $code
```

some things I have tried for getting the token that did not work are:

```
encoded_creds="$(echo -n "$client_id:$client_secret" | base64)"
(curl -X POST -s https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token \
  -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -H "Authorization: Basic $encoded_creds" \
  -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=$code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A$port%2F") > "auth_token"
```

and

```
encoded_creds="$(echo -n "$client_id:$client_secret" | base64)"
(curl -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/v1/swap" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "code=$code") > "auth_token"
```

along with many other similar variations, all either returning nothing, or a 401 error that no token was provided.

Comment: This seems relevant to this question :) https://gist.github.com/hughrawlinson/1d24595d3648d53440552436dc215d90

Comment: similar yes, except that the attempt to make $response just returns an empty string for me, with or without doing POST in the curl call.